# Automatically add underscores between multiple words in a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a cell with multiple words and I need an underscore between them.

using

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(C8,MATCH(1,INDEX((MID(C8,ROW(INDIRECT("2:" & LEN(C8)-1)),1)=" ")*(ISERROR(VALUE(MID(C8,ROW(INDIRECT("2:" & LEN(C8)-1))-1,1))))*(ISERROR(VALUE(MID(C8,ROW(INDIRECT("2:" & LEN(C8)-1))+1,1)))),0),0)) & "_" & MID(C8,MATCH(1,INDEX((MID(C8,ROW(INDIRECT("2:" & LEN(C8)-1)),1)=" ")*(ISERROR(VALUE(MID(C8,ROW(INDIRECT("2:" & LEN(C8)-1))-1,1))))*(ISERROR(VALUE(MID(C8,ROW(INDIRECT("2:" & LEN(C8)-1))+1,1)))),0),0)+1,255),C8)
```

This is only adding the underscore to the first word.

Comment: Difficult to understand your formula without sample data, but what about `=SUBSTITUTE(<your cell>, " ","_")`

Comment: Almost worked, but now I have one long underscore after the last word in my cell.  How to I end the command?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change *all* spaces for underscores use:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(C8," ","_")
```

To remove multiple spaces at the start or end of your string, use:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(C8)," ","_")
```

Comment: Same result.  Works, but now I have one long underscore after the last word.

Comment: You probably have multiple spaces at the end of your string. See the edit to my answer